# Dynamically created listbox isn't recognized by VBA

Tags: vba, listbox, coreldraw

listboxes are created by opening a csv file with data (8 column, 9 row data sample)

```
..........................
For r = 0 To ListBoxSayisi
Set cTR = New Control
Set cTR = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.ListBox.1", "ListBox" & r + 1, True)
For i = 1 To UBound(arrX)
cTR.AddItem arrX(i, r + 1) 'r + 1
Next i
With cTR
.Width = 100: .Height = 300: .Left = (100 * r) + 50: .Top = 15
End With
.......
```

then trying to get data from these listboxes

CorelDraw VBA does not recognize that these are "ListBoxes". Even named clearly on them "Listbox" and check if listbox names are goin; ListBox1, ListBox2 .... by integer numbers etc.

VBA never accepts that they are real "ListBox".

How to address listboxes in CorelDraw?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i got it...

referenced by name like this and solved this problem:

`Me.Controls("Listbox" & i)` (inside brackets was the important point) ;)